Google Chrome Crashes on Ubuntu 24.04
Google Chrome on my Ubuntu 24.04 system has started crashing on startup. I have many windows and tabs. The first two starts will always crash and the third will always succeed. This is the behavior after a normal exit. On the first two I get
[84727:84727:1222/150422.445686:ERROR:atom_cache.cc(229)] Add WM_CHANGE_STATE to kAtomsToCache
[84727:84727:1222/150442.471211:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(214)] Creating shared memory in /dev/shm/.com.google.Chrome.Dje9OY failed: Too many open files (24)

On the third which succeeds I get just the WM_CHANGE_STATE
It is not a ulimit on the number of open files, I have that set way up to 10240. Previously with roughly the same number of tabs and windows, it worked with the limit at 1024. I don't know what to make of the /dev/shm error. The kernel shared memory limits have not changed.
I know Chrome has a strategy of doing a safer startup after two crashes, and presumably does not open as many tabs on startup. If its a particular tab thats the problem, I don't see it in the debug log.
Any ideas?
